# Prove fibonacci with matrixes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

I have a question which i could not figure out the answer to, it was the hardest of them all that i got and i couldnt figure it out, its a proof of fibonaccis serie using matrixes and i need som help

The question:
The Fibonacci Numbers are recursively defined as $f_0 = 1$, $f_1 = 1$ and $f_{n+2} = f_{n+1} + f_n,$ for all $n ≥ 0$.
Set $M = \binom{1\quad1}{1\quad0}$ and consider the powers $M, M^2, M^3,$ ... of this matrix. Prove that $M^n = \binom{f_n\quad f_{n-1}}{f_{n-1}\quad f_{n-2}}$ for all $n ≥ 2$. Powers of a matrix are the products
$M^0 = I,\quad M^1 = M,\quad M^2 = M*M,\quad M^3 = M*M*M, . . . .$

can someone help and show me how to do this please? the proof

Comment: Use induction on $n$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is true for $n=2$, as the product 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
f_2 & f_1 \\ f_1 & f_0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now assume the statement is true for $n$; we will show it is true for $n+1$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
f_n & f_{n-1} \\ f_{n-1} & f_{n-2} 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
f_n + f_{n-1} & f_{n-1} + f_{n-2} \\ f_{n}  & f_{n-1} 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{n+1} & f_{n}  \\ f_{n}  & f_{n-1} 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
Thus induction is established and the statement is true for all $n\geq 2$.